# Can't return JSON object from python using django-ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Trying to apply this ajax plugin for django https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax
I'v used ajaxPost successfully, but can't apply ajaxGet

In views.py. In python all data is printed fine.

```
    @ajax
    def notify(request):
     notifications = Notification.objects.filter(whom=request.user.profile)
     for acd in notifications:
        print(acd)
        print(acd.choice_afl)
        print(acd.whom)
        print(acd.who_did)
     return {'notifications': notifications}
```

In html:

```
    $('.notifications_button').click(function(){

    ajaxGet('/notify/', function(notifications){

         for(var acd in notifications){

             alert(acd.choice_afl)
            $('#the_very_nw').html(acd.choice_afl);

         }
})
```

If I alert `noty` I get `"notifications"`, if I alert `acd.choice_afl` I get `undefined` (or just nothing if insert into html), despite in python I get the sting result I need . What is wrong? Doesn't python object transforms into JSON object?

EDIT: Also for safe I serialized django object into json like this. No changes

```
data = serializers.serialize("json",notifications)
return {'notifications': data}
```

EDIT2: I watched the structure of JSON

```
 var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data),null,2); 
$('#the_very_nw').html(jsonPretty);
```

and it looks like this. So I missed 'fields' but it changed nothing. Still nothing is printed. And that is in case if I return HttpResponse :

```
[ { "fields": { "how_much_new_notifications": 0, "number_of_new_notifications": 0, "who_did": 2, "question_answered_object": null, "whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F" }, "model": "blog.notification", "pk": 1 }, { "fields": { "how_much_new_notifications": 0, "number_of_new_notifications": 0, "who_did": 2, "question_answered_object": null, "whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F" }, "model": "blog.notification", "pk": 2 }, { "fields": { "how_much_new_notifications": 0, "number_of_new_notifications": 0, "who_did": 2, "question_answered_object": null, "whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F" }, "model": "blog.notification", "pk": 3 }, { "fields": { "how_much_new_notifications": 0, "number_of_new_notifications": 0, "who_did": 2, "question_answered_object": null, "whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F" }, "model": "blog.notification", "pk": 4 }, { "fields": { "how_much_new_notifications": 0, "number_of_new_notifications": 0, "who_did": 2, "question_answered_object": null, "whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F" }, "model": "blog.notification", "pk": 5 }, { "fields": { "how_much_new_notifications": 0, "number_of_new_notifications": 0, "who_did": 2, "question_answered_object": null, "whom": 1, "choice_afl": "F" }, "model": "blog.notification", "pk": 6 } ]
```

Comment: inspect the response body in browser dev tools network (or in browser by opening that url). I'm not a python dev but it sure does not look like you are encoding any json and the response can only contain one json object or array representation(with nested levels of course). What does response look like? Use jsonlint.com to validate it

Comment: @charlietfl check the edit please

Comment: I don't know this rails ajax wrapper but I'm sure it has error handling methods that you whould implement and check what the arguments return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in your JS code. Try rewriting the loop as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
   var acd = notifications[i];
   $('#the_very_nw').html(acd.choice_afl);
}
```

Currently `acd` are just indeces of the array, not its elements (a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/4904093)).

Comment: @НазарТопольский strange but nothing is printed and even  alert doesn't work inside your loop. Hmm

Comment: Can you try doing something like `console.log(notifications)`?